# Table value update that will include a where statement

Tags: vba, sql-update

I have one table that has field names "StepX" where X is 10 thru 1420 stepping in 10s.  I have another table that has row values of 10 through 1420 and these values between the two are connected.  I need a routine that gets the "X" from the field name, finds the equivalent "X" valued row in the other table, grabs the value from a column (on the same row where X resides) in the second table and places that value in the first table on a row under field name "StepX".

looked through the various questions and answers and I can't find how to handle the fieldname changing as I loop through.  the do until works but I do not see the value in the first table.

```
Dim dbs As Database
   Dim MarkerNumber As Integer
   Dim MarkerTotal As Integer
   Dim stSQL As String


   MarkerTotal = 1420
   MarkerNumber = 10

   Set dbs = CurrentDb

    Do Until MarkerNumber = MarkerTotal

        stSQL = "UPDATE tbl_Changes SET tbl_Changes.[Step'markernumber'] = SELECT_TypeTest set TypeTest WHERE SELECT_TypeTest.Order =10"

        MarkerNumber = MarkerNumber + 10
    Loop
```

I put in what you have and it didn't work probably because I didn't give you the whole story.  since I submitted the question, I changed my update query as follows and it works: UPDATE tbl_Changes, SELECT_TypeTest SET tbl_Changes.step10 = IIf([SELECT_TypeTest]![InstrTest]>0,"Need","N/A")
WHERE (((SELECT_TypeTest.Order)=10));
need help turning this into code with the MarkerNumber sequencer.

Answer (score 0):

Minor changes

```
   Dim dbs As Database
   Dim MarkerNumber As Integer
   Dim MarkerTotal As Integer
   Dim stSQL As String


   ''MarkerTotal = 1420
   ''MarkerNumber = 10

   Set dbs = CurrentDb

   For MarkerNumber = 10 To 1420 Step 10

        stSQL = "UPDATE tbl_Changes SET Step" & Trim(Str(MarkerNumber)) & " = TypeTest " & _
               " FROM ( SELECT TypeTest FROM  SELECT_TypeTest  WHERE Order = " & Trim(Str(MarkerNumber))

        ' now that the sql is built, then execute it
        dbs.Execute

   Next
```